# Encoding special characters even with the raw filter due to include

Tags: templating, include

Hey guys i have something odd happening and I don't understand why:

The opening of my template i set a variable `{% set text = component.textarea ?? null %}`

Lower in my template i have the following: `{% set text = include('_components/_dataTypes/textarea') %}`

That template only currently has `{{ text }}` in it so as of right now doesn't mean much.

Then last in my template i have `{{ text|raw }}`

However characters are still encoded.

I've found that if i remove the include template, even though all it includes is `{{ text }}` that `|raw` works. I should note that if i put `|raw` in the include template, it still does not work.

Why is that? Is it a parse order thing or what's going on there that causes the include to ignore the filter? I should note that using Wordsmith and the `|pde` filter does work regardless of the include... however characters such as `< > ' "` etc. are still encoded, where as they are not without the include.

Please help me understand why this is occurring. Thank you.

Comment: I was asked if i am using Javascript at all in any of these places or if it is all Twig/HTML. The answer is there is ZERO javascript, it is strictly html/twig.

Comment: Interesting, in all these years I'd never considered setting a variable using the return value of an include. I didn't even know it was possible! I see how that could be helpful, though maybe a macro or embed would work around any parse order issues.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the Discord you are probably looking for the [source](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/functions/source.html) function.

The reason the include doesn't work is covered in the old PR for (what eventually became) source. It's probably best I link all that discussion than try to put it in my own words here!

- [Initial discussion with your problem](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/issues/1229)
- [First PR](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/pull/1230)
- [Further PR after discussion (the source function as it is now)](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/pull/1257)